# Oracle: missing SELECT keyword, when using CTE

Tags: oracle

- I am getting an "Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword" error message when I run the following query.
- The purpose of the query is to find the duplicate rows
  can any one help me

my query

```
with RowNumCTE as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parcelid,PROPERTYSPLITADDRESS,SALEDATECONVERTED,SALEPRICE,LEGALREFERENCE order by id) rn
from housedata
)
```

Comment: See also: [WITH (Common Table Expressions)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a final query to your CTE, like

```
with RowNumCTE as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parcelid,PROPERTYSPLITADDRESS,SALEDATECONVERTED,SALEPRICE,LEGALREFERENCE order by id) rn
from housedata
)
SELECT rn FROM RowNumCTE ;
```

Comment: could you please help me once more: I have the following code: with RowNumCTE as (
    SELECT ID, parcelid,PROPERTYSPLITADDRESS,SALEDATECONVERTED,SALEPRICE,LEGALREFERENCE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY parcelid,PROPERTYSPLITADDRESS,SALEDATECONVERTED,SALEPRICE,LEGALREFERENCE order by id) rn
    from housedata
    )
    DELETE from RowNumCTE
    where rn>1                                                                                   get an error as previous that you solved

Comment: You have it almost see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad62894a3c5ab1cd75a787e1e87e933a

Comment: vielen dank fuer Ihren helfen